# Python Probability Union

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was wondering if there was a python package/inbuilt function for carrying out probability union  P(A u B) and intercept P(A n B) calculations. I know the algorithm to follow but thought if there was an inbuilt, reduces redundant code. I have cases where I have 6 different probabilities to union and intercept.

Comment: Python has built-in sets with intersection, union etc

Comment: what is this package/link to documentation for these? I couldn't find these

Comment: A useful answer to the depends on how you want to represent the probability distributions.  Please tell as that first.  For example, what do you mean by "I have 6 different probabilities"?

Comment: I think you mean Bayes formula. It's just four terms, you should be able to build something yourself fairly trivially. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes'_theorem

Answer (score 2):

Python has inbuilt library for sets, [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html)

`x.union(y)` will create a new set with elements of both x and y

`x.intersection(y)` will create a new set with elements common to x and y

Example:

```
>>> x = [{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {3, 4, 5}]
>>> set.intersection(*x)
set([3])
```

Apologies if i have misunderstood your question. But a bit more information would be helpful